# Wordpress Tax_Query on Custom Post Type Term, Tax Query not filtering by term

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called "Franchises".
I have a custom post type taxonomy called "Directory", which sorts the Franchises by their industry.
On my website, I have created a shortcode, where you pass the function an ID (Which is relative to the term's ID), like so.

```
[CUSTOM_FRANCHISES term="8"]
```

The problem I have, is that it is not filtering by the term. The function gets the posted value, in the above case 8, and I can successfully return the posted value. When the data from the shortcode is returned, it displays everything, and doesnt filter by the term.

```
function custom_franchises($atts){
    ob_start();
    global $post;
    $set_cat = $atts['term'];
    $args = new wp_query(
        array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'franchise',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'tax_query' =>
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'directory',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $set_cat,
                )   
            )
    );      
    while($args->have_posts()){
            $args->the_post();
            $post = get_post();
            $postid = $post->ID;
            
            $htmlcontent .= "<p>".$postid."</p>";
    }
    return $htmlcontent;
    ob_end_clean();
}
add_shortcode('CUSTOM_FRANCHISES', 'custom_franchises');
```

If anyone can shed any light that would be appreciated.
Thankyou.

Comment: I did attempt to utilise a similar function from within the taxonomy's own loop, fetching the term ID by slug and doing it that way. but had the same issue.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters: _“Important Note: tax_query takes an array of tax query arguments arrays (it takes an array of arrays).”_

Comment: FYI: No need for output buffering, if you don’t use any code that actually writes directly to the output buffer. And `ob_end_clean();` of course won’t ever execute here, because you placed it after the `return` statement that _leaves_ the function.

Comment: Cheers CBroe, I added an extra array around the tax query paramaters and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_franchises($atts){
        ob_start();
        global $post;
        $set_cat = $atts['term'];
        $args = new wp_query(
            array(
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'franchise',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'directory',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => array($set_cat),
                    )   
                )
            )
        );      
        while($args->have_posts()){
                $args->the_post();
                $post = get_post();
                $postid = $post->ID;
                
                $htmlcontent .= "<p>".$postid."</p>";
        }
        return $htmlcontent;
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    add_shortcode('CUSTOM_FRANCHISES', 'custom_franchises');
```

Comment: Hi, this results in the same issue , Thankyou for answering, the problem was solved when i double arrayed my tax query

Comment: It's not the same you are not using "term_id" and array of $set_cat, I updated code please check it

Comment: Please remove ob_start() and ob_end_clien() and also declare $htmlcontent="" in above of the whiile loop